# date range query in mongodb 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to query mongodb for retrieving records from the today midnight to current time, but its giving an error in the query , please help
Sample Records :

```
 {
 "myDate" : ISODate("2017-07-17T11:06:17.874Z"),
"_id":"xxxx"
  }
  ,
  {
 "myDate" : ISODate("2017-07-17T11:06:17.874Z"),
"_id":"yyy"
  }


 db.runReadCommand(
 {
aggregate : 'mycollection',
pipeline : [

{$project : {a:new Date (),myDate:1}},
{$project : {myDate:1,a:1,
    b : {$dateFromString : { dateString : {$dateToString:{date : '$a',format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}}}}}
 ,{$match : {myDate: {$lte : a}}}
],cursor:{batchSize : 10}})
```

Regards
Kris

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) library to find start of the day and the present time

With just a find query

```
db.collection.find({
  myDate: {
    $gte: moment().startOf("day").toDate(),
    $lte: moment().toDate()
  }
})
```

With aggregation

```
db.runReadCommand(
  {
    aggregate: "mycollection",
    pipeline: [
      { $match: {
        myDate: {
          $gte: moment().startOf("day").toDate(),
          $lte: moment().toDate()
        }
      }}
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: There is a 5 microsecond (you get the idea) window where that will fail because $gte is looking at yesterdays date and $lte is looking at the new date from the second call to moment.   
Just sayin'....

Comment: `$gte` will look for start of the day... Suppose today is **28/7/2018** then it will look for `ISODate("2017-07-28T00:00:00.000Z")` with `$lte`--> `ISODate("2017-07-28T11:06:17.874Z")`

Comment: Assume it is 28/7/2018 and 5 micros to midnight and 29/7/2018.
The $gte call to moment().startOf("day").toDate() yields midnight 28/7/2018.
Microseconds pass.
Then the $lte call to moment() yields 29/7/2018 (plus a few micros).
So now the query picks up ALL of yesterday (28/7/2018) to now (29/7/2018)

Answer (score 1):

An approach without requiring `moment`:

```
var r = [
     // These are not today:
 {_id:0, ts: new ISODate("2018-07-26T07:00:00.000Z")}
,{_id:1, ts: new ISODate("2018-07-26T22:00:00.000Z")}

     // These are today and before now (when I wrote this)
,{_id:2, ts: new ISODate("2018-07-27T00:00:00.000Z")}
,{_id:3, ts: new ISODate("2018-07-27T10:00:00.000Z")}

     // These are AFTER now (when I wrote this)
,{_id:4, ts: new ISODate("2018-07-27T20:00:00.000Z")}
,{_id:5, ts: new ISODate("2020-01-01T20:00:00.000Z")} // the future!
 ];

db.foo.drop();
db.foo.insert(r);

now = new Date(); 
sod = new Date(now);

// Cheapo way to set time elements to midnight:
sod.setHours(0);
sod.setMinutes(0);
sod.setSeconds(0);
sod.setMilliseconds(0);

print("now: " + now);
print("sod: " + sod);

db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {$and: [ {ts: {"$gte": sod}}, {ts: {"$lt": now}} ]  }}
            ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Is it possible for rephrasing your query with strict json as I am using jongo for running the command

Comment: JSON is a data carrier, not a language.   No variables, expressions, etc.
The goal you seek is independent of MongoDB.   The concept of "now" and "today" are very much in the application space.   You can do the same thing in jongo.  I am guessing.   You have to get sod and now variables into the jongo query expression framework.